# Push Button and Filter button location suggestions

Tags: buttons, filter

In the home page of the app., I have PickUp , Delivery and filter button. The filter button gives more filter options. The three buttons I believed are not in the right position on the screen. Not sure if needs to be inside the container where it is currently or if it should so up below the search bar or beside the search bar. Also, I am confused if the pickup and delivery button should be there as the quickest option to find food or if it is best to just have it inside the filter button.

Please see two screens below :

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| Home page | Clicking the filter button on the app home page |

Comment: I think it should be inside the filters option, or at least have a label to specify those are filtering methods (it wasn't clear for me until I saw the content of the second screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are examples from 2 similar apps:

1. Delivery and Pick-up buttons are at the very top, the filter option is below:

[image]

Filter screen:

[image]

2. Here is another example:

[image]

After user selects an option, the filter appears next to search bar:

[image]

Filter screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. Before I answer my views I would like to know certain information.

1. Does the choice of the food I can buy change if I choose pickup or delivery as an option. If not does it make sense to have that option in the begining. Dont you think that the user should first decide what to order and at the time of checkout should decide delivery or pickup.
2. You can make the experience much better by asking user (some AI by tracking the browsing behaviour and recording it in the database) based on previous buying, should we activate you delivery option at this address.

Hope this helps

Comment: though filter should definetely be there as its a choiceessential to find what the user wants to find, but instead of a button there are other ways of making a filter